# WPF: Is there a built-in TreeGrid / TreeListView?

Tags: wpf, controls, treelistview

I need something just like this:

[image]

(I need both the TreeView and the ListView aspects. That is, Hirearchy and Columns.)

But, I need it in WPF.  is this something that is built in, or am I going to have to build it myself?

I assume it has to be somewhere in the framework, since VS2010 is build in WPF.

Edit:
I have managed to get some of the functionality that I want using a TreeView and some grids with their Columns bound to a Parent grid's columns, but there are too many quirks in the functionality.

Edit 2:
I still have as-of-yet not found a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

This post on MSDN makes use of native WPF to achieve a TreeView/Grid hybrid. It is based on the TreeView and Grid controls. It supports a treeview with multiple columns, but does not support sorting or filtering

http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9898803

EDIT: I have recently integrated this code and it works very nicely, gives you exactly what you want: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered *Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid* ?

You can see a Demo of **Full Version** [here](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html).

There's also a **Community** Edition as part of [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)™ - [Ms-PL license](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/license)

[List of the features in Full version](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/Features.html)
[List of the features in Community Edition](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Features%20of%20Xceed%20Extended%20WPF%20Toolkit%20Plus.html)
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a table-styled compilation.

P.S.

1. By using *[Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)* (WPF Spy utility) and *Spy++* on Visual Studio 2010 (Professional edition), I've found that the *TreeGrid* you see inside *Watch*, *Local*, and *Autos* tool-windows, is called ***TREEGRID*** which is **not** a Wpf component. (But I'm not sure what it is).
   Interesting though, I've found that the *Breakpoints* tool-window was built by using two components side-by-side - *SysTreeView32* and *SysListView32*
2. I'm not related to Xceed in any way :-)

Edit:
It seems that Hierarchy can be achieved on both Version, but **Master-Detail** is only present in the **Full version**, and on the **Community version** you can get only by using **Groups**.
:-(

Comment: on Visual Studio 2017, most of the _ToolWindow_ are `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.GenericPaneClientHwndHost` hosted within `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame+ContentHostingPanel` but the inner controls (Tree+Grid) are **not** real WPF controls. These are probably some internal (& native?) controls stored somewhere near Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fake this display using specially-aligned shared Grid objects in your templates for TreeView...

However I don't believe the one you see in Visual Studio is actually a WPF control implementation, it was there in Visual Studio 2008 as well and is likely either a custom native control or custom Windows Forms control.

Good news, though: if you must absolutely have this experience and want it soon... it's a total hack, but: use Windows Forms interop with your WPF app.

A Microsoft employee blogged a winforms `TreeGridView` implementation back in '06:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20060113083903/http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20080305082707/http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/18/new-link-for-treegridview.aspx

Comment: I think that that is WinForms.

Comment: Correct. I have noted above, "it's a total hack, but use Windows Forms interop with your WPF app."

Comment: all links broken

Comment: @Welcor Here is the original blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20060113083903/http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx, and the prebuilt binaries are available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20080305082707/http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/18/new-link-for-treegridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This one works like a charm for me.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control

- you implement ITreeModel with GetChildren und HasChildren. Best to check the example code with the registry example to understand how its done. For some reason the developer forgot to add a simple example...
- you have to add dependency properties yourself to the control to get it to work with MVVM. So it may need some tweaking. Add this to TreeList.cs to be able to bind the TreeModel:

```
public ITreeModel TreeModel
{
    get => (ITreeModel)GetValue(TreeModelProperty);
    set => SetValue(TreeModelProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeModelProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TreeModel",
        typeof(ITreeModel), 
        typeof(TreeList), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnModelChanged));

private static void OnModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var treeList = (TreeList) d;
    treeList.Root.Children.Clear();
    treeList.Rows.Clear();
    treeList.CreateChildrenNodes(treeList.Root);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) seems quite good to me...

Comment: ObjectListView is built on WinForms, not WPF

Comment: ObjectListView can be used in WPF but when I tried it there where a lot of flickering issues which I did not have with the same implementation in Winforms so I cannot advice using it.

Answer (score -1):

You can somewhat obtain this behavior with the DataGrid by following [this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20150510181140/http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iv-templatecolumns-and-row-grouping) (scroll the the *Fake grouping with the help of the ViewModel* section).

The tutorial's solution works well enough, but scrolling can get laggy and it's behavior unpredictable when some rows are collapsed.

**Update**: I changed how the children are hidden.  Instead of collapsing rows, I removed items in the bound ObservableCollection.  Now scrolling works perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the `TreeView`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Page.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="StaticXml" XPath="root/foo">
            <x:XData>
                <root xmlns="">
                    <foo a="_File">
                        <foo a="New">
                            <foo a="_Project..." />
                            <foo a="_Web Site..."/>
                        </foo>
                        <foo a="C_lose"/>
                        <foo a="E_xit"/>
                    </foo>
                    <foo a="_Edit">
                        <foo a="Cu_t"/>
                        <foo a="_Copy"/>
                        <foo a="_Paste"/>
                    </foo>
                </root>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=foo}">
            <AccessText Text="{Binding XPath=@a}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaticXml}}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I need multiple columns.  I have been trying for about 4 hours to coax multiple columns out of TreeView, but the result is a little less than impressive.