# Header aligned(Tixati-style) HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to show files with their directory structure. The default HierarchicalDataTemplate does the job just fine, but the problem is, I want to also show a few more attributes of the file. I can also do that, but they are not aligned, like they would in a ListView. How would I do this just like how Tixati does it?

Here are a few pics to help make the question clearer:

What I have currently:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbDR6.png (sorry, I don't have 10 reputation yet.)

What I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQjcx.png

Comment: You need a special control often named a `TreeGrid`. You have plenty of implementations but unfortunately AFAIK only a few and limited free versions. You can check this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703209/wpf-is-there-a-built-in-treegrid-treelistview